# How to hide a static variable in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, binding

I have three classes with same methods and only constants are different. So what I wanted is to create one base class, which contains all the methods and to add three child classes which contain only constant variables. It looks like it is not possible to do so because of the dynamic binding. Please look at the example:

```
public class Parent {
    static String MY_CONSTANT = "bla bla";
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(MY_CONSTANT);
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    static String MY_CONSTANT = "hello world";
}

public class Greetings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child hey = new Child();
        hey.printSomething();
    }
}
```

The output is "bla bla", but I want the output to be "hello world".

Is there some solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to hide a static variable in Java?

This is all you can do for variables: hide them. Although variables can be inherited, they cannot be overridden.

As actual values are class-specific and static, the only way to reuse a method in this scenario, is by making it take parameters:

```
public class Parent {
    static String MY_CONSTANT = "bla bla";

    public void printSomething(String something) {
        System.out.println(something);
    }

    //Essentially, Parent.MY_CONSTANT becomes just the default
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(MY_CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

And the child can choose what it sends (overriding is basically to reuse the API):

```
public class Child extends Parent{
    static String MY_CONSTANT = "hello world";

    @Override
    public void printSomething() {
        //MY_CONSTANT is hidden and has "hello world"
        super.printSomething(MY_CONSTANT); 
    }
}
```

The above design allows calls from the test class to behave predictably (or, rather, intuitively):

```
Child hey = new Child();
//Behaves as Child.
hey.printSomething();
```

---

**EDIT:** Since the getter is an instance method (understandable as you depend on the instance type to read the correct value), you can expose to children the field, or a setter, and all sorts of hiding would be suppressed completely:

```
public class Parent {
    protected String myConstant = "bla bla";

    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(this.myConstant);
    }
}
```

And children would just have to set the value in an initialization block:

```
public class Child extends Parent{
    public Child() {
        myConstant = "hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ernest, are there other solutions, maybe using instance variables or constructors? Since it would be overwhelming to create another method for each method in the base class (my base class contains a lot of different methods i want childs to inherit) and then override all these methods in child classes.

Comment: @user3214767 I'll edit to suggest an accessible field in parent

Comment: @user3214767 Answer edited. Using one instance field actually makes sense

Comment: thanks a lot. I was worried that it is not OK to use instance variables for constants but in this case it should be good.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to override the `printSomething()` method:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    static String MY_CONSTANT = "hello world";

    @Override
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(MY_CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

It might be cleaner, though, to have a method that returns the value of the static variable. Then you can override that method, and call it from the base class:

```
public class Parent {
    static String MY_CONSTANT = "bla bla";

    public String getConstant() {
        return Parent.MY_CONSTANT;
    }
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(getConstant());
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    static String MY_CONSTANT = "hello world";

    @Override
    public String getConstant() {
        return Child.MY_CONSTANT;
    }
}

public class Greetings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child hey = new Child();
        hey.printSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Parent {

    static String MY_CONSTANT = "bla bla";

    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(Child.MY_CONSTANT);
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
        static String MY_CONSTANT = "hello world";

        @Override
        public void printSomething() {
            super.printSomething(); // definition define in parent class
        }
    }
public class LeapTEST {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

            Child child = new Child();
            child.printSomething();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a **constant** you should combine the **static** modifier with the **final** one. The final modifier indicates that the value of this field cannot change (have a look to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), in the related section). (A static variable is common for all instances of the class. A final variable can not change after it has been set the first time).

If you have a look the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html):

> A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name if it is
>   static, or by using a field access expression that contains the
>   keyword super or a cast to a superclass type.

So you can refer a static variable outside the class using ClassName.myStaticVariable:

And since you should access them in this way, there is also no need to worry about hiding them.

Answer (score 0):

I reached the same problem and my solution instead of extending the parent class was by using an enum like this:

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    PARENT("Parent constant"),
    CHILD("Child constant");
    private String myConstant;
    MyEnum(String s) {
        myConstant = s;      
    }

    public void printConstant(){
        System.out.println(myConstant);
    }
}
```

And then, call the `printConstant` method of the desired enum like:

```java
MyEnum.CHILD.printConstant();
```

Of course, this is limited but it suites my case so i hope it will help someone too.